# Distorted display after upgrading the kernel to 5.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 32 bit

Tags: 18.04, kernel, graphics, 32-bit, visual-artifacts

Athlon XP with Radeon 9550. Ubuntu 18.04 lxde with compiz.

Screenshot with kernel 5.4.0-42

[image: desktop screenshot shows missing characters in applications and distortions]

Screenshot with kernel 5.3.0-62

[image: all looks fine in similar screenshot]

I tried running it with openbox instead of compiz; the problem is still there.

Console screens (those available on ctrl+alt+fN) are not distorted.

Is it a known bug?

Comment: In 18.04, your kernel should be something like `4.15.0-112-generic`. Is there a specific reason you're on 5.4?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 0):

I just figure that out, but I am not sure whether my method would work for you. My system is Windows10-Ubuntu dual boot system with Ubuntu grub menu for selecting OS.

My environment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 64bit, kernel: Linux 5.4.0-70-generic

machine: Ryzen 7 5800x, rtx2060 super, MSI MAG b550 tomahawk, TPLINK WIFI 6 ax3000 PCIe WIFI card (this WIFI card is the reason I upgrade my kernel from 4.15 to 5.4)

In short, I solve it by installing proprietary driver for graphic cards in recovery mode.

The initial reason I do the upgrade is because kernel 4.15 does not support WIFI 6 and kernel 5 does. So I upgrade my kernel on Ubuntu 18.04 using (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_-_Bionic_Beaver)

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

When I reboot my machine, the screen was distorted with pepper noise pixels and did not response. Seems like it want to show some lines but it met some display problem. I restart my machine and in the grub menu, I select advanced options for Ubuntu and enter recovery mode for kernel 5.4. Just select resume and it just display the desktop correctly! I checked the kernel version, yes it is 5.4 and it was function normally in recovery mode. I added the nvidia PPA and installed proprietary driver 460 in additional drivers GUI. Reboot normally (not recovery mode), it works!

Afterthought: When I tried to install ubuntu 18.04 with bootable usb, I encountered exactly the same problem (pepper noise pixels). But it still displayed some message at that time, which is r8169 unknown chip xid 641. So it is probably related to this?

Hope this post would helps somebody out. Good luck with Linux!

Comment: this may be the right approach, but just a note that presumably OP needs AMD drivers (if any) rather than nvidia